# JPA: Column should be unique inside its parent.

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, unique

I have 2 tables:

```
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {

 @Column
 @NotNull
 @Size(min = 1)
 @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z]{1}[A-Za-z0-9_]*")
 private String token;

 @ManyToOne(optional = true)
 @JoinColumn(name = "b_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
 private B b;

 ...
}

@Entity
public class B implements Serializable {

 @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "b")
 private List<A> a;

 ...
}
```

The `Token` in entity A should be UNIQUE **within B**. 
For example there is a *Token1* within B1 and also a *Token1* within *B2*, but there can 
be a second *Token1* inside B1.

I'm using JPA with Hibernate.

How do I achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By creating a [`UniqueConstraint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/UniqueConstraint.html) on the combination of the foreign key and the token.

On entity `A`, something akin to the following:

```
@Table(
    name="a", 
    uniqueConstraints={
        @UniqueConstraint(columnNames={"b_id", "token"})
    }
)
@Entity
public class A implements Serializable {
    // ...
}
```